# how to apply hover effect on draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a draggable area which has multiple divs which can be dragged. i wish to apply hover effect on draggable div. i just wish to call class ZOOM on mouse over effect. here is my code

---

```
    $('<div style="background-image:url(images/'+numbersShuffled[i]+'.png);">'+ numbersShuffled[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numberIndex ).attr( 'id', 'card'+i ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {    
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',


      revert: true
    } );
  }
```

---

here i want to zoom that background image on mouse over. for zooming effect i have the css

---

```
    .zoom {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;

    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    background-position: center center;
}

.zoom:hover {
    background-size: 150% 150%;
}
```

Comment: your statement `i just wish to call class ZOOM on mouse over effect` and CSS code `.zoom:hover` are totally contradictory to each other. could you please elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `.zoom` class on your elements. Right now they don't have any classes. Just modify to `$(<div class="zoom" ...` in the jQuery selector or call `.addClass('zoom')` and the CSS will do the rest.

Comment: it not reacting to zoom class by simply calling class to div

Comment: Can you provide a runnable snipet?

Comment: if i simply apply zoom class to a normal div, then it doing its work, but when i include class to this div i.e div inside jquery of draggable div, then zoom class not responding

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#theming) jQuery UI draggable provides the following classes: `ui-draggable`, `ui-draggable-dragging`. Try applying the zooming style on these classes as well and tell me how this goes

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid using INLINE CSS**

Use it as a class on the DIV.

```
<div class=".zoom.dragable"> Drag me!</div>
```

**Suggestion:**

You have used the jQuery selector in an inadequate way.
I recommend selecting from a class, not be creating a select-able object. Like here:

```
$( ".dragable" ).draggable();
```

Basically add the *class='dragable'*  to any HTML object you want to make drag-able.
**Also:** Do try to use CSS in the style section or in an external file.

**Piecing everything together**

```
<script> 
  $( ".dragable" ).draggable();
</script>

<style>
      .zoom {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;

    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    background-position: center center;
}

.zoom:hover {
    background-size: 150% 150%;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div class=".zoom.dragable"> Drag me!</div>
</body>
```

As a bonus you should also try these CSS effects:

Zoom In:

```
.zoomIn:hover
{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
        transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

Zoom Out:

```
.zoomOut:hover
{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: plz dont change my div. i have to do in that way only. because that div is manual getting data from database.i have big page depend on this. i have only shown small part to u. plz call class zoom in my draggable div only